Route53 cname record for AWS WebSocket
I have a websocket url wss://blahblah.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/qa/ in my qa environment. I added a route 53 CNAME record entry for my domain qa-my-domain.com mapped to blahblah.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com.
But I am getting a 403 when I tried to connect using my CNAME. It connects fine when I use the websocket url. Any ideas or suggestions?
